# How to rename a common column name in multiple tables mysql

Tags: mysql

I have multiple tables in a db with common name like `x_a,x_b,x_c...`and a common column name `zzz`.I want to rename `zzz` to `yyy` and change the datatype.How can I do it in mysql?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE old_col new_col new_datatype`

Comment: I wat to rename all the tables at a time, Is it possible?

Comment: you can write stored Procedure and iterate through all tables from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES